# Still getting Bad Request while passing JSON data to Spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, bad-request

I found a lot of answers on the same questions and still noone of those works for me :( and I feel already tired of misunderstanding from my side. Problem is clear: I am passing JSON string to Spring controller via @RequestBody and get "400 Bad Request" response. When I use @ModelAttribute - everything works, but all values are null.

I am using POSTman for sending requests. Here is code:

*Controller:*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
logger.info("UserController -> createUser call made");
    if (user != null) {
        logger.info("UserController -> createUser(" + user.toString() + ")");
    } else {
        logger.info("UserController -> createUser(null)");
    }
    user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    return userService.createUser(user);
}
```

*Entity class:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

@Transient
private String name;

private String email;

/*
 * 1 - male
 * 0 - female
 */
private boolean gender;

private Date createdDate;

@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public boolean getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(boolean gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getFirstName() + " " +
           getLastName() + ", " +
           (getGender() ? "male, " : "female, ") +
           getEmail() + ", id = " + getId() +
           " created on: [" + getCreatedDate() + "]";
}
```

*JSON passed:*

```
{"gender":true,"lastName":"Novosad","firstName":"Oleg","createdDate":"Sat Sep 20 16:16:48 EEST 2014","email":"adminnovik@gmail.com"}

Headers: Content-Type:application/json
```

*Configuration:*

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please, let me know if you will need other info. Appreciate your answers!

**UPDATE:**

After turning logs for spring to be "All" (in log4j.properties put line: log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL) I found the problem: Spring could not parse Date value which I wanted it to parse.

Comment: If you turn your Spring logs to debug, Spring will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: setting "log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL" is very useful for me, thx.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be getting the 400 because your `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and its `ObjectMapper` cannot deserialize the date you've provided.

The simplest solution is to provide a custom date deserializer that uses your date format.

```
class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
        try {
            return format.parse(jp.getText());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // or handle any other way you like
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
```